# Expo - send link with email...failure

Tags: expo, mobile-application

I am using expo to work on my app and wanted to send a link to a friend to test it out. When I click on "send link with email..." I get an error message:

> oops, sending link to 'friendsemail@gmail.com' failed."

I haven't published the app to expo, so I was curious if I need to do this before I am able to send the link. Is this a bug or am I missing a step before I can share the expo link?

I have tried to restart the metro bundler, restart the terminal, but neither are working. I am about to join the expo slack group but wanted to see if this was an issue others have ran into and have a quick solve for.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you signed into Expo on your development machine? You can do this by pressing 's' key. After signing in, try sending the mail, it should work.
See the image below:
[image: Snapshot in VS code]

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in with your expo account. Press 's' key in terminal, you will get option of sign in . After successful signing in try again sending mail, it should work.